# JSP 2.0 Custom Tag: Unable to find setter method?

Tags: jsp, exception, jsp-tags

Am quite new to "JSP"; I am using Eclipse Juno with xampp (Tomcat 7.0.28).
I have created the following jsp tag file:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" body-content="empty" description="Read Property from the Application's properties file."%>  
<%@ attribute name="Key" required="true" description="Key for searching Properties File."   type="java.lang.String"%>  
<% System.out.println(Key); %>
```

when using the same in JSP as:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="app" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/app" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><app:random/></title>
</head>
<body>
    <app:getProp Key="APP.TITLE"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the tag file in: /WEB-INF/tags/app.
But while executing the file i get the following exception:

*Sep 23, 2012 7:49:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MedCamp] threw exception [/index.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) Unable to find setter method for attribute: Key] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) Unable to find setter method for attribute: Key
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.evaluateAttribute(Generator.java:2865)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateSetters(Generator.java:3089)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateCustomDoTag(Generator.java:2507)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1748)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3490)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*

Kindly let me know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The name of an attribute passed to a tag file should begin with a lowercase letter. Rename your `Key` attribute to `key` and your code will work.